# Upload photo to a custom list using visual webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a list, ListPersonalDetails, for storing personal details of students. It has fields like firstName, lastname, address etc. It also contains a field to store the photo which is of type image. I created a visual webpart, StudentPersonalDetails, to add items to ListPersonalDetails. It contains a file upload control used to browse photo. I need to upload the image along with other details to the list.

used the following code part to update the list:

```
SPListItem studentDetailsItem = 
    SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["ListPersonalDetails"].Items.Add();

studentDetailsItem["StudentID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
studentDetailsItem["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
studentDetailsItem["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text; 

//studentDetailsItem["photo"]=need to upload photo
studentDetailsItem.Update();
```

Comment: Are you asking how to upload the photo using the control, or how to save the image to your SharePoint list once it's uploaded?

Comment: I have file upload control in my visual webpart. I need to upload the file browsed, when i click save button to the field of type 'Image' in a custom list.